# Large HTML tables to PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf-generation

Is there any good library or other way to convert large `HTML` tables that has horizontal as well as vertical scrolling.
I tried `jsPDF` in fiddle, and the table is squeezed to some extent and then it is trimmed off.
`Google` sheets has kind of better `PDF` generator that reduces the size of the page itself and tries to fit in.
And as much as possible the style should be retained.

Comment: Have you tried the [jspdf autotable library](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable)

Comment: Here you can use this library https://docraptor.com/documentation/jquery. Hope it helps.

Comment: @ABiswas I need to generate table along with the parameters, which is not part of the table.

Comment: @AshishPanchal Is there no standalone library. I do not want to make any API requests for it. Something that can handle request in the browser itself.

Comment: jsPDF is the only in-browser option, although it won't generate near as nice PDFs as DocRaptor.

Comment: @yuvrajzohan : Then I don't see any other library other than jsPDF or you can implement some server side library if you are using node js then many npm packages are available.

Comment: @AshishPanchal This particular part of code to be converted to PDF in fact needs to run in server too and in node,js. Is there any package that works well enough?

Comment: @yuvrajzohan : you can find `html-pdf`, `html-to-pdf` npms which can convert your html to pdf easily.